# Group a set of rows based on a column

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have case where I am getting the data from from my database and it looks like this:

[image]

I am using Entity Framework database first and a stored procedure to get this data.This is the model that I get back:

```
public partial class GetELearningSessionsForStudent_Result
{
    public int LessonNumber { get; set; }
    public string LessonTitle { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TargetDate { get; set; }
    public string EventTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to be able to group LessonNumber and use it as a key , that would contain the following:

```
     KEY                                   Data
{LessonNumber AND LessonTitle} {Status , TargetDate , EventTitle}
```

I have been trying to do this for hours and it feels that I am somehoe missing something.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
listOfItems.GroupBy(key => new { key.LessonNumber, key.LessonTitle },
     data => new {data.Status, data.TargetDate, data.EventTitle});
```